# Prevent accidental deletion of spanner databases

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-iam

In order to reduce the chance of data loss due to engineering errors, how can a specific spanner database grant exclusive permissions to a single service account?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Generally there have several people that are granted broad rights within a project on google cloud.  This is so that they can deploy production services, handle pagerduty incidents, etc..  **As far as I can tell it is not possible to subtract already granted permissions.**  Ideally IAM would allow removing all rights to a single spanner database, except to a specified service account that is intended to access it.

**Is there a way to prevent deletion of a google spanner database even though developers have been granted broad (i.e. owner) access to the project?**

Comment: I think I can get this done if a create a new project that no one really has any permissions on and creating the google spanner database in that new project.  I could then grant permissions to a service account and use the credentials in the other project?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently.

However, in the future there may be the ability to create custom roles in IAM, where you can give all permissions except those you want to restrict on Cloud Spanner. You would then assign this custom role to the people who need broad, but not full project, permissions. See the Alpha documentation for [creating and managing custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) for more details.

> Cloud IAM also provides the ability to create customized Cloud IAM
>   roles. You can create a custom Cloud IAM role with one or more
>   permissions and then grant that custom role to users who are part of
>   your organization. Cloud IAM provides a UI and API for creating and
>   managing custom roles.

In the meantime, your workaround of isolating the Spanner instances in a separate project seems reasonable.

Comment: It looks like you can create a role from a normal role, which means I can create one from Owner then remove permissions, which is neat!  It isn't clear if my custom role that is based on a regular role will continue to inherit changes from the one it was created from.  I'll watch for it to leave alpha.

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches.

1. If you're worrying about a Spanner Database getting dropped, you can use the `--enable-drop-protection` flag when creating the DB, to ensure it cannot be accidentally deleted.
2. You *can* make negative permissions through [IAM Deny Policies](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-overview) in Google Cloud, to expressedly prevent someone, like a developer group or Service Account, from taking a specific action.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can tell it is not possible to subtract already granted permissions.

In the interim, you could try and [revoke access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) to the broadly accessed role account, and limit their access to [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/iam) DatabaseReader|Viewer|DatabaseUser roles. A special role account can then be granted permissions for Cloud Spanner Admin|DatabaseAdmin role (restricted developer membership).